Elasticsearch: how to collapse data first then filter in one query
I have a lot of duplicated data with the same ID. Can I collapse the data in that index first, then filter according to the desired result in the same query?
I had tried inner_hits in collapse and then post_filter but it didn't work
  "size": 1000,
  "collapse": {
    "field": "item.item_id.keyword",
    "inner_hits": {
      "name": "latest",
      "size": 1,
      "sort": [
        {
          "calculated_at": "desc"
        }
      ],
      "_source": ["item_id", "timestamp", "is_active"]
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {
    "term": {
      "item.is_active": false
    }
  }
}


You can use collapse parameter.
GET /my-index-000001/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "message": "GET /search"
    }
  },
  "collapse": {
    "field": "user.id"
  },
  "sort": [ "user.id" ],
  "search_after": ["dd5ce1ad"]
}


Thank you but it still dont work in my case.
I have 2 records with the same id, in the record there is an is_active field separated by true and false. I want to collapse first to filter out the newest record (for example, the one with is_active is true). Then when I filter by false I will no longer see the record with that id.

Hey @Good, you're right. If you use filter or post_filter with is_active: false and if the old data has false value for that field collapsed result will show the available one which is the old one. To achieve what you want you have two options, first one is use a unique id per document and get rid of duplicated records second is run the query without filter and grab the ids from the result, add ids to terms query as filter and add other filters like is_active: true and send another query.

Or you could use the terms-top_hits aggregation pair
Sample documents
POST /collapse_and_filter/_bulk
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"item":{"item_id":"1","is_active":false}}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"item":{"item_id":"1","is_active":false}}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"item":{"item_id":"1","is_active":true}}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"item":{"item_id":"2","is_active":false}}
{"create":{"_id":5}}
{"item":{"item_id":"2","is_active":false}}

Query with the aggregation pair and the bool filter
GET /collapse_and_filter/_search?filter_path=aggregations.by_item_id.buckets.key,aggregations.by_item_id.buckets.document_list.hits.hits
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "item.is_active": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "by_item_id": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "item.item_id.keyword",
                "size": 10
            },
            "aggs": {
                "document_list": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "_source": ["item"],
                        "size": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Filtered response
{
    "aggregations" : {
        "by_item_id" : {
            "buckets" : [
                {
                    "key" : "1",
                    "document_list" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "_index" : "collapse_and_filter",
                                    "_type" : "_doc",
                                    "_id" : "1",
                                    "_score" : 0.0,
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "item" : {
                                            "is_active" : false,
                                            "item_id" : "1"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index" : "collapse_and_filter",
                                    "_type" : "_doc",
                                    "_id" : "2",
                                    "_score" : 0.0,
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "item" : {
                                            "is_active" : false,
                                            "item_id" : "1"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key" : "2",
                    "document_list" : {
                        "hits" : {
                            "hits" : [
                                {
                                    "_index" : "collapse_and_filter",
                                    "_type" : "_doc",
                                    "_id" : "4",
                                    "_score" : 0.0,
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "item" : {
                                            "is_active" : false,
                                            "item_id" : "2"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "_index" : "collapse_and_filter",
                                    "_type" : "_doc",
                                    "_id" : "5",
                                    "_score" : 0.0,
                                    "_source" : {
                                        "item" : {
                                            "is_active" : false,
                                            "item_id" : "2"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}


Thank you, but this response is so hard for FE to handle.Solution : I have set unique docID for each record.
